# Placing objects over something that is not a plane using ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I would like to do something similar to the Apple Campus AR demo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRowAw4kJeQ

This demo happens over a model of the campus, which is definitely not a plane.

I have two main questions:

-How can I place anchors over surfaces like this?
-How can I use this anchors to determine where I have to put the 3d model when there is no clear plane?

Comment: iOS 11.3 added image detection in Arkit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience  . You might be able place QR codes on the surfaces of the model, which then allows you  to add some anchor points on the model/object you want to track. But its not something I have done yet... so can’t give anymore help.

Comment: Not sure how they did it. You can place QR code in plane and use it generate model over larger area. Try hittest on bounding box of qr code.